# VbScript ADODB.RecordSet RecordCount returns -1

Tags: vbscript

My question today is a rather simple one. What I have is a VB Module that contains the code to return me an ADODB.RecordSet object with records fetched from a SQL Query that has been executed. It works like this:

```
sSql_SerCheck = "SELECT DISTINCT Serial FROM dbo.WipReservedSerial WHERE  Serial LIKE '" & serialTempSearch
sSql_SerCheck = sSql_SerCheck & "' ORDER BY Serial DESC "
dbGetRecordSet(sSql_SerCheck)
```

Then the results sit in object rs that is accessed like the following

```
 temp = rs(0) 'For the value at the first column for the first record
 rs.MoveNext  'This moves to the next record in the record set
```

Now what I am trying to do here is to the number of records contained within this recordset object. Now I did some research on the class and found there is a
RecordCount att.

So what I want to do is simple:

```
if( rs.RecordCount > 0) then
    serCheck1 = rs(0)
    MsgBox serCheck1
end if
```

The problem is my RecordCount returns -1. I found this article http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_recordcount.asp that states that record count will return -1 for the following:

Note: This property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor.

Note: The Recordset object must be open when calling this property. If this property is not supported it will return -1.

How do I get this object to return the correct number of records??

The code for the VB Module is added below:

```
Public cn, rs


'Specify pSQL as SQL Statement
Function dbGetRecordset(sSql)
dbCloseConnection()

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.CommandTimeout = 600
cn.Open(Conn & SystemVariables.CodeObject.CompanyDatabaseName)
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sSql, cn, 3, 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As your `rs.RecordCount > 0` just checks whether the recordset is not empty, you can avoid .Recordcount (and all it's problems) by testing for `Not rs.EOF`
2. Don't trust secondary sources; the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contain "... and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, **depending on the data source**". So maybe your provider is to blame. In that case (or when you really need a specific number), a `SELECT COUNT()` would be a workaround
3. Don't use magic numbers as in `rs.Open sSql, cn, 3, 3`, but define (and doublecheck) your Consts like `adOpenStatic`, `adLockOptimistic`, ...

Answer (score 5):

From Help

```
Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
oRs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
oRs.Open sSQL, sConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Help has a full description of Cursors in *What is a Cursor* (ADODB Programmers Guide - Windows Software Development Kit).

You'll burn resources either locally or on the server to get a record count. If you are going through the data anyway, just count them.

This is how to go through a recordset one at a time.

```
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set connection = CreateObject("adodb.connection") 
connection.open "Driver=your driver details"

If connection.State = 1 Then
    Set myRecord = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    sql= "select * from...."
    myRecord.Open sql, connection
    i = 0
    Do While Not myRecord.EOF
        i=i+1
        myRecord.MoveNext
    loop
    msgbox "RecordCount="&i
    myRecord.Close
END IF   
set myRecord = nothing
set Connection = nothing
```

Comment: Given .Recordcount and SELECT COUNT() this manual rigmarole is not even ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I was finding that the vbscript version of this was flaky... the best option seemed to use a CursorLocation of 3.. vbscript didn't seem to understand adUseClient.

````
    set conn=CreateObject("ADOdb.connection") 
    conn.CursorLocation = 3
    conn.open DSNQ
    set rs = conn.execute("select * from sometable order by 1 desc")
    msgbox (rs.RecordCount & " records"     )```
````